# Best Practice - Where to place a managed assembly when real purpose is to expose TLB file

Tags: com, vb6, assemblies, com-interop, managed

I have an environment where there is a combination of managed and non-managed executables being run for a particular suite.

I have a scenario where the only reason I have a managed assembly (in this case) is because code was easier to write in C# than in VB6.

My 'main' application, written in VB6, needs to make a call to this assembly.  So I create the TLB file, so its COM callable.

Now for deployment, is it better practice to place the managed assembly 'with' the tlb in the windows system directory? to have them both in the same place?  Seems to me a bit easier to manage that way.

Or the managed assembly (not-signed since it isn't to be shared among diff apps) should just go to the BIN of the application dir, and the TLB moved to the windows\system32 and registered there.

Overall it seems more straight forward to keep them together, but it doesn't seem to be the correct way to do things.

Thx for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above.  You only need the type library when you *compile* your VB6 program.  It does not need to and should not be deployed on the user's machine.  There's a small corner case where a type library can help with marshaling an interface across an apartment or process.  That won't be the case in a VB6 app.

Comment: Note that if that COM object raises events that you want to handle (early bound) in VB, you must still distribute and register the tlb file.

Comment: No, that's nonsense.  There's no early binding without a compiler.

Comment: hmm you don't need to register the tlb?  Regasm xxx.dll /tlb: xxx.tlb /codebase    .. it's actually called late bound.

Comment: @HansPassant Maybe so, I still spent many hours tracking down what was essentially a "type mismatch" error with events that goes away as soon as I register the typelib on the target machine. Unregister it and they break again.

Comment: That doesn't register the type library, it only *generates* it.  So your VB6 project can use it.  Regasm *does* register the [ComVisible] classes.  So you can *debug* your VB6 code.  They need to be registered on the user's machine as well.  If you actually use late binding in your VB6 code then there's no reason at all to ask Regasm to generate the type library.  It is only necessary if you use Project + References in your VB6 project.

Comment: if you don't register it, how does even the late binding effect know where the dll is located.

Comment: Please do keep the *two* things that Regasm.exe does apart.  One: it registers [ComVisible] classes, required.  Two: it can generate a type library when you use the /tlb option, optional.  It does *not* have an option to register a type library.  Late binding still requires registering the [ComVisible] classes or the code won't run.  The only thing you can skip is telling the compiler about them.

Comment: ok, i see... i think i forgot the reason for the entire statement i had... i was early binding for trouble shooting... but needed it primarily to work as late binding. but didn't exactly understand what was needed or not... tx for the explaination.   So back to the original question... i guess since i'm only left with an assembly.. if there is a BIN folder, it is appropriate to place there.

Comment: You can put it anywhere you like.  The GAC is a good place to avoid DLL Hell.  On the user's machine, not yours.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd put both of them in your application's installation folder or under the `Common Files` structure.
The `System32` folders are ideally just for the system files. (Ignoring history for the moment :)